# Insert data from java into redis

Tags: java, arrays, text, redis

I want to write a Java program that gets as input (in the command line) the name of a relation's specification file and inserts relation's data into Redis in an appropriate format below

File(txt) contents:

```
Worker
ID
FName
LName
City
Age
;
18900;Giannis;Papadopoulos;PAtisiwn 28, Athens;42
15222;Fotini;Nikolaou;Kifisias 33, Marousi;34
99877;Kostas;Panagiotopoulos;Karaiskaki 44, Petralona;29
```

**first line(Worker) contains only table's name**

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    //Connecting to Redis server on localhost 
    Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost", 6379);
    System.out.println("Connection to server sucessfully");
    //check whether server is running or not 
    System.out.println("Server is running: "+jedis.ping()); 
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(".../testing"))) 
        {   
        String sCurrentLine; List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) { 
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine); 
            //list.add(sCurrentLine);
            /*for( String MyFile: sCurrentLine.split(";")){ System.out.println(MyFile); jedis.hmset(MyFile); } */ 
           System.out.println(sCurrentLine); 
           jedis.set(sCurrentLine, " "); 
        } 
    //String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]); 
    //System.out.println(list); 
        } catch (IOException e) 
    { e.printStackTrace(); }
 }
```

all these I tried, sorry for bad demonstration ....do you have any idea how to insert in a properly format this kind of text file?

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Have you looked at the java redis clients here http://redis.io/clients#java ?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
   //Connecting to Redis server on localhost
       Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost", 6379);
 System.out.println("Connection to server sucessfully");
       //check whether server is running or not
       System.out.println("Server is running: "+jedis.ping());
       try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(".../testing")))
   { String sCurrentLine;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
    //list.add(sCurrentLine);

Comment: /*for( String MyFile: sCurrentLine.split(";")){
    System.out.println(MyFile);
     jedis.hmset(MyFile);
     } */
     System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
      jedis.set(sCurrentLine, " ");
   
    }
    //String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
    //System.out.println(list);
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    
   } 
       
   }

Comment: all these i tried,   sorry for bad demonstration ....do you have any idea how to insert  in a properly format this kind of text file..    ??

Comment: is your file in csv format?